# A weird phenomenon in Ember-CLI dist/, I cannot modify anything inside it

Tags: ember-cli

In my Ember-cli project, I put some static assets, such as images and icons into the /dist/static/image directory. Then I build the project (I forgot the details in this part).
Then when I tried to modified some picture inside that folder (I wanted to change some parts to be transparent), I found that I cannot change anything inside.
For example, when I used a new pic to replace the old one, and then I run ember, I found that the new pic was replaced by the old one automatically.
I am not so sure about the internal mechanism, and I tried to use git, but that didn’t help.

Comment: To my knowledge you shouldnt be doing any modification in the dist folder. You do all your development in your regular project folders and then run `ember build` to create a dist folder for deployment. Images should go in the public/images folder that is alongside your app folder

Comment: The dist folder is overwritten whenever `ember build` is run, your static assets should go in [public](http://www.ember-cli.com/#folder-layout)

Comment: The question is solved by reading the [documentation](http://www.ember-cli.com/#folder-layout)

Answer (score 0):

`/dist` is just that - it gets wiped out on each build and reloaded with the distributable files. What you are looking for is `/public`